# Is it possible to create a simple answering machine in android?

Tags: android, audio-recording

I'm thinking of creating an answering machine in android that automatically alerts the caller that he/she has reached the answering machine after an alloted time and then records the message. Is it possible in android?

Answer (score 2):

No. You do not have any way to play audio to the caller.

Comment: Is there really no way to do that in android? What about just playing a beep sound or recording the audio from the caller?

Comment: Not only do you not have any way to play audio to the caller, but you have no way of answering the phone.