# Audio file to mic

Tags: android

I need a way to put an audio file to the mic, during a phone call, so that the other user, on the other side of the phone call can hear the audio file.
It would be best to mix it with the mic.

I could not find anything, is there some one that knows how to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: So far there's no way you can do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053712/is-it-possible-to-create-a-simple-answering-machine-in-android

Comment: It's technically possible to do on some devices, assuming that you have access to the full source code for the given platform, and can build and flash your own ROM. But if you're an app developer, the answer is "No".